# Accessing elements from player.getIframe() object?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

As per https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
player.getIframe():Object

This method returns the DOM node for the embedded <iframe>.
```

How can I access the elements of the DOM node like I can do with the parent page's DOM, such as `document.getElementById("example")`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the children under that player.getIframe():Object

```
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R98hoTffg0E?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
```

in short, they are:

```
id, frameborder, allowfullscreen, title, width, height, src
```

To access them, you'd do something like:

```
player.getIframe().id
player.getIframe().title
```

`player` is the youtube player instance taken from the same docs you provided.

Comment: @nogui Are you saying that true access to the DOM is not possible and that these six attributes are what can be accessed?  The API docs section is called  'Accessing and modifying DOM nodes' is there true access and ability to modify?  Where can find how?