# YouTube Player API Accessing and Modifying DOM in iframe

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

YouTube player API docs has a section on [Accessing and modifying DOM nodes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes) .

Which seems to say that using the method `player.getIframe()` returns an object with the DOM of the iframe having 'read/write' properties.  Which is sort of unusual for an iframe, but google is controlling content and browser, so (I was hoping) that access could be granted while security is assured.

However, using the method `player.getIframe()` I personally get 4 attributes and NO childnodes(--Nodelist[]--) or children (--HTMLcollection[] -- ) and cannot seem to use js/jQ dom access methods like `querySelector()`.

Disappointingly, this seems to be the experience reported [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132294/2455159) .

Is there any way to access the DOM within the YT player API iframe, am I misreading the docs or do the docs need to be updated?!?

Comment: The documents say nothing about read/write access.

Comment: @KenSharp Maybe it could be that I don't understand the phrase 'access and modify' when the docs read 'access and modify DOM in iframe'. What else does it/ could it mean? Please.

Comment: @StephanLuis from reading the docs, I believe they mean accessing *your* DOM nodes (i.e. the iframe node) not *the iframe's* DOM (i.e. the actual player)

Comment: @solidau I guess 'modify' could describe the .destroy() method and access would be the ability to grab the iframe other than by using $('iframe').  But, in fact $('iframe').remove would do the same as .destroy().   So I was hoping that the access and modify would do more!  Thinking through security, could YouTube provide access as if the frame were 'same origin'? Off the top of my head I don't see any added vulnerability.